# What is a good chess engine to play against on an android phone?

Tags: analysis, engines

I have an android phone, and I have the Chess Free app. It is nice in that you can set the computer difficulty level and record games, and even play against another human, but it severely lacks analysis features. I've been having problems finding a good chess analysis program with analysis features on android. Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Droidfish](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.petero.droidfish&hl=en) app on Android is what you need. It has professional level GUI(with sophisticated analysis functions) with Stockfish engine pre-installed.

Comment: Thanks so much. What percent difficulty on this app would correspond to a ~1450 strength?

Comment: Around %0 between %20 will be good for ~1450 FIDE I think.

Answer (score -1):

Do try 'Analyze This' App, especially for analyzing games with multiple Chess engines. Can even automatically Analyze games with English commentary!
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.analysis

(Disclaimer: I am the developer! Happy to help!)

Comment: I'm so sorry but I tried out your app and for some reason was not able to get it to work. I will give it another go sometime. No offense, but your app was the reason I asked this question. I think it's probably user error but in most cases of user error the developer is at least a little bit at fault.

Comment: No problem! Android has more than 9k different Android devices, and it can be a difficult task for us developers to make things work on all of them! What was the nature of the problem (were you setting up a position or loading games from pgn or entering your own moves?) Anyways you could also email me at pereiraasim@gmail.com and we can continue this discussion. Thanks!